# stop service in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got some problems in android studio. I would like to use `stopService()` to close my service, but its not working.

- Here is my project going

1. click button in MainActivity.java and Start Service Service_Record.class

```
            cardView_Start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startService(new Intent(this,Service_Record.class));
                }
            });
```

2-1. create notification in Service_Record.class(Service) onCreate()

```
        //step 4 create action
        intent_sleep=new Intent(Service_Record.this,Service_RecordData.class);
        intent_sleep.setAction("stop");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent_sleep =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Service_Record.this,1,intent_sleep,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        //step1 create channel
        createNotificationChannel();
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //step2 setting context
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel_Sleep")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.rec)
                .setContentTitle("Recording")
                .setContentText("It is recording.Press stop button when you awake.")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText("It is recording.Press stop button when you awake."))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .addAction(R.drawable.stop,"Stop",pendingIntent_sleep)
                .setOngoing(true);

        //step3 create
        notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());
```

2-2. upload value to firebase for every 10 secs in Service_Record.class(Service) onCreate()

```
            if(timer!=null){
                timer.purge();
                timer.cancel();
            }
            timer=new Timer();
            TimerTask timerTask=new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    insertDot();
                }
            };
            timer.schedule(timerTask,0,10000);
```

3. close service by clicking notification's button in Service_RecordData.java (receiver)

```
public class Service_RecordData extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (action != null) {
            if (action.equals("stop")) {
                mNotificationManager.cancel(0);
                
                //Something wrong
                context.stopService(new Intent(context,Service_Record.class));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. Mainfest.xml

```
        <receiver android:name=".Service_RecordData" />
        <service android:name=".Service_Record"/>
```

- I found out the problem since my firebase kept uploading value after I closed the notification and APP. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found how to fix it. But I still can't figure out the problem. If anyone know what happened, I'll give you the mark. THX.

```
context.stopService(new Intent(context,Service_Record.class));
```

into

```
Intent intent_service = new Intent(context,Service_Record.class);
context.stopService(intent_service);
```